# cumulative probability plot from frequency table

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way to plot the cumulative probability from a frequency table? I mean a "smooth" version of it, similar to the way `geom_density()` plots.

So far, I managed to plot the individually calculated probabilities as points joined by lines, but it doesn't look very good.

Comment: You should provide example data.

Comment: Also, you should look at `geom_smooth`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generate some test data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sort(sample(1:100, 20))
p <- runif(x); p <- cumsum(p)/sum(p)
table <- data.frame(x=x, prob=p)
```

You can use geom_smooth from the ggplot2 package.

```
require("ggplot2")
qplot(x=x, y=p, data=table, aes(ymin=0, ymax=1)) + ylab("ecf") + 
geom_smooth(se=F, stat="smooth", method="loess", fullrange=T, fill="lightgrey", size=1)
```

As an alternative, an easy way to specifiy smoothing by a parameter try DeconCdf from the decon package:

```
require("decon")
plot(DeconCdf(x, sig=1))
```

If you want to use ggplot, you first have to transform the Decon function object in a data.frame.

```
f <- DeconCdf(x, sig=1)
m <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=f$x, p=f$y), aes(x=x, y=p, ymin=0, ymax=1)) + ylab("ecf")
m + geom_line(size=1)
```

Use the sig-Parameter as your smoothing parameter:

```
f <- DeconCdf(x, sig=0.3)
m <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=f$x, p=f$y), aes(x=x, y=p, ymin=0, ymax=1)) + ylab("ecf")
m + geom_line(size=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This version plots a histogram with a smoothed line from `geom_density`:

```
# Generate some data:
set.seed(28986)
x2 <- rweibull(100, 1, 1/2)

# Plot the points:
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(data.frame(x=x2),aes(x=x, y=1-cumsum(..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=..count..)) +
  geom_density(fill=NA, color="black", adjust=1/2) +
  scale_y_continuous("Percent of units\n(equal to or larger than x)",labels=percent) +
  theme_grey(base_size=18)
```

[image]
Note that I've used 1 - "cumulative probability" due to individual preference (I think it looks better and I'm accustomed to dealing with "[reliability](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/File:WB.8_weibull_reliability.png)" metrics), but obviously that's just a preference that you could ignore by removing the `1-` part in the `aes`.